# Rest API endpoint to generate and download MS Word docx document

Tags: java, rest, ms-word, apache-poi

I have a Rest API endpoint to generate and download MS Word docx document (I'm using org.apache.poi.xwpf to create a docx file). My controller looks like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/download")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=sample.docx")
                .body(new InputStreamResource(myService.generateWord()));
    }
```

I'm building the XWPFDocument with standard POI library methods in myService.generateWord() method. If I save docx document on HDD and after that return `Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("temp", "sample.docx"))` everything works fine (both documents, on HDD and downloaded from browser, are OK), but if I'm trying to return `docx.getDocument().newInputStream() //docx is XWPFDocument` than downloaded file is corrupted, I get an "MS Word found an unreadable content" error. One more thing - if I open downloaded docx by notepad++ - I can read xml code and it has 7kb size while open proper docx document will show encrypted unreadable text and it has 4kb.

Actually, I can use "write to disk and download" option, but I want to know how to download docx document directly from RAM, without saving it on disk.

Comment: If you can download the document from disc it seems the problem has nothing to do with REST. Did you try to generate the Word document and save it directly to file? If this produces a corrupt document you have to look at the code generating the document.

Comment: If I save generated document on disk - file is OK. I think, there could be 2 options: some header in ResponseEntity is missing or docx.getDocument().newInputStream() doesn't return whole file content (missing some specific docx xml tags)

Comment: `XWPFDocument.getDocument` only gets the `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocument1` which is only one part of the `*.docx`. A `*.docx` is a ZIP archive containing multiple files in a special directory structure. To get the whole from the `XWPFDocument` one needs using `XWPFDocument.write` to write it to a `OutputStream`. There is no way around. But the `OutputStream` may be a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to avoid a file.

Comment: ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> could possibly be used to get an outputstream for the response that can be used for the XWPFDocument write.

Comment: XWPFDocument.write() do the thing, I'm writing docx to ByteArrayOutputStream and after that just return resultStream.toInputStream(). @AxelRichter, post your message as answer so I can accept it